# Arithmetic in pandas HDF5 queries

Tags: pandas, hdf5, pytables

Why am I getting an error when I try to do simple arithmetic on constants in an HDF5 where clause?  Here's an example:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(10), "B": np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)})
>>> store = pandas.HDFStore('teststore.h5', mode='w')
>>> store.append('thingy', d, format='table', data_columns=True, append=False)
>>> store.select('thingy', where="B>50")
   A   B
0  0  61
1  1  63
6  6  80
7  7  79
8  8  52
9  9  82
>>> store.select('thingy', where="B>40+10")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    store.select('thingy', where="B>40+10")
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 682, in select
    return it.get_result()
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1365, in get_result
    results = self.func(self.start, self.stop, where)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 675, in func
    columns=columns, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4006, in read
    if not self.read_axes(where=where, **kwargs):
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3212, in read_axes
    self.selection = Selection(self, where=where, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4527, in __init__
    self.condition, self.filter = self.terms.evaluate()
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 580, in evaluate
    self.condition = self.terms.prune(ConditionBinOp)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 122, in prune
    res = pr(left.value, right.prune(klass))
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 118, in prune
    res = pr(left.value, right.value)
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 113, in pr
    encoding=self.encoding).evaluate()
  File "c:\users\brenbarn\documents\python\extensions\pandas\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 317, in evaluate
    raise ValueError("query term is not valid [%s]" % self)
ValueError: query term is not valid [[Condition : [None]]]
```

Querying directly on the underlying pytables object seems to work:

```
>>> for row in store.get_storer('thingy').table.where("B>40+10"):
...     print(row[:])
(0L, 0, 61)
(1L, 1, 63)
(6L, 6, 80)
(7L, 7, 79)
(8L, 8, 52)
(9L, 9, 82)
```

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not supported. I suppose it could fail with a slightly better message. it is trying to and the 2 nodes (the comparison and the +10) and doesn't know how to deal with it as it's not a comparison operation.

I suppose it could be implemented but IMHO is needlessly complex

Comment: Needlessly complex to specify an expression in the where clause?  If it's supported by the underlying Pytables query, why can't pandas just pass it through?

Comment: because their is quite a bit of parsing involved this is an AST transform; much more than 'just pass it thru'

Comment: Maybe I will ask on the list, but what does pandas gain by doing this instead of just accepting a straight Pytables query string?  It seems somewhat perverse to create a custom query syntax that is less powerful than the underlying Pytables one.

Comment: well you would have to create it your self with the correct syntax, properly infer all types, provide type conversion, transformations and operator precedence so it's pretty non trivial

Comment: I don't understand why you would have to do all that.  The Pytables query syntax already provides all the operator precedence and all the rest of the expression handling and allows you to query on the column names as well as passed condvars.  I can do `store.get_storer('thingy').table.where("B>X**2-49*X+10", condvars={"X": 40})` and it works fine.

Comment: well then go ahead and try it with a string or datetime or categorical or any non trivial expression.

Comment: I can imagine it wouldn't work with datetimes, yeah.  It seems to work fine with strings.  However, it is still surprising behavior to disallow valid Pytables queries that were actually used on a given call in order to support complex datetime queries that weren't actually needed.  I think there is room for improvement.  I'll raise an issue.

Comment: I see your issue - my point is that the parsing IS necessary and IMHO complex where queries are rarely useful - but if u think u can fix this gr8

Comment: I created the issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11284).  I'm curious about what sorts of queries fail with plain Pytables and whether there's a way to allow the ones that work and only interfere with the ones that wouldn't otherwise work.